# set array object from other array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 arrays array1, array2.

1. array 1 objects: userName, userId
2. array 2 objects: userId, msg
3. i want to get array3: userId, userName, msg

**Array1:**

```
[{ userName: 'vimal', userId: 789 },
    { userName: 'kabilan', userId: 456 },
    { userName: 'yathavan', userId: 123 }]
```

**Array2:**

```
[ { userId: '123', msg: 'hi' },
{ userId: '789', msg: 'yth' },
{ userId: '789', msg: 'hu' } ]
```

i want to compare 2 arrays and get output like this.
**Array3:**

```
[ { userId: '123', userName: 'yathavan', msg: 'hi' },
{ userId: '789', userName: 'vimal', msg: 'yth' },
{ userId: '789', userName: 'vimal', msg: 'hu' } ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An off-the-shelf, "functional programming" approach:

```
var users = [{ userName: 'vimal', userId: 789 },
    { userName: 'kabilan', userId: 456 },
    { userName: 'yathavan', userId: 123 }]

var messages = [ { userId: '123', msg: 'hi' },
    { userId: '789', msg: 'yth' },
    { userId: '789', msg: 'hu' } ]

var user_message_list = [];
messages.map(function (message) {
    return users.
        filter(function (user) {
            return user.userId == message.userId
        }).
        map(function (user) {
            return {
                "userId": user.userId,
                "userName": user.userName,
                "msg": message.msg
            }
        })
})
.forEach(function (item) { // eliminate nested layers 
    user_message_list.push.apply(user_message_list, item)
})
```

[JSFiddle Functional](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/qm1pLqzd/)

---

*Explanation:*

Two arrays of objects, one a list of users, and the other a list of messages by some of those users.

You're wanting to flesh out a report of the messages showing the usernames, so start with the `messages` array and loop through it. Now, for each message loop through the `users` list and retrieve the corresponding username.

The "loopy" approach is like this:

```
var messages_users = []
var message_user = {}
for (ii=0; ii < messages.length; ii++) {
    message_user = {
        "userId": messages[ii].userId,
        "msg": messages[ii].msg
    }
    for (iii=0; iii < users.length; iii++) {
        if ( messages[ii].userId == users[iii].userId ) {
            message_user.userName = users[iii].userName
        }
    }
    messages_users.push(message_user)
}
```

[JSFiddle Loopy](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/wq5vwcd1/)

Alternatively, using Functional Programming concepts, start by `map`ing a function to each item in the `messages` array. That function takes the `users` array and `filter`s it to find the corresponding user object for the current message, and `map` on that result to combine the current message information with the filtered user result. At this point you have an object wrapped in an array, since the `map` and `filter` methods return arrays. Therefore, the final operation is to loop using the `forEach` method to remove the extra array layer. Some JavaScript libraries have a `concatAll` or better yet `concatMap` method that hides that extra loop. In that case you'd have something like this:

```
var user_message_list = messages.
    concatMap(function (message) {
        return users.
            filter(function (user) {
                return user.userId == message.userId
            }).
            map(function (user) {
                return {
                    "userId": user.userId,
                    "userName": user.userName,
                    "msg": message.msg
                }
            })
})
```

The benefit here is tighter coupling between the language nomenclature and the procedural concepts. For example: `filter(...` vs. `for (i=0; ... if ( arr[i] ===...`. Both constructs loop and select items based on criteria, hence `filter`.

More on [Functional Programming in JavaScript](http://jhusain.github.io/learnrx/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a users array indexed my the userid that contains the username;

```
var users = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
  users[arr1[i].userId] = arr1[i].userName;
```

now make your output array, and go through the 2nd array.  using the users array to insert;

```
var arr3 = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++)
  arr3.push({userId:arr2[i].userId, userName:users[arr2[i].userId], msg:arr2[i].msg});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this, if `userId` value was not a String in  ary2:

```
var ary1 =[{userName:'vimal', userId:789}, {userName:'kabilan', userId:456}, {userName:'yathavan', userId:123}];
var ary2 = [{userId:123, msg:'hi'}, {userId:789, msg:'yth'}, {userId:789, msg:'hu'}];
function specialMerge(ar1, ar2){
  var r = [];
  for(var i=0,l=ar1.length; i<l; i++){
    var p = ar1[i];
    for(var n=0,c=ar2.length; n<c; n++){
      var m = ar2[n];
      if(p.userId === m.userId){
        r.push({userId:p.userId, userName:p.userName, msg:m.msg});
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
var resultArrayOfObjects = specialMerge(ary1, ary2);
```